# Wait for user confirmation before caching files for service worker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

Im using npm module register-service-worker to register my service worker and cache the files for my app. Everything works and I can use the app offline by caching the whole application files.

So when the user first opens the app in the browser everything is downloaded to the user's device. However I would like to give the user the option to download or not the files displaying a modal with both options.

This is my function to register the service-worker:

```
export default function registerServiceWorker() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
      registrationOptions: { scope: './' },
      ready (registration) {
        console.log('Service worker is active.')
      },
      registered (registration) {
        console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
      },
      cached (registration) {
        console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
      },
      updatefound (registration) {
        console.log('New content is downloading.')
      },
      updated (registration) {
        console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
      },
      offline () {
        console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
      },
      error (error) {
        console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This function is called in the main.js file, the entry point for the app. I have tried to called it only after the user clicks the 'yes' button but nothing happens.

Also thought of using the MessageChannel API to communicate between the client app and the service worker, I sucessfully recieve the message but can't make the 'onupdate' event wait for the user input.

Is this possible anchieve in some way?